# How can I echo some text that contains characters such as $, !, ' and " without modyfing the text itself, with no escape sequences?

Tags: bash, echo

An example of what I'm trying to achieve:

`echo "BSPDIR := "${@os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(d.getVar('FILE', True)) + '/..')}"" >> somefile.txt`

I want the whole text in the outermost quotes inside "somefile.txt", and not have to modify it with escape sequences. I don't mind using something else other than `echo`.

I appreciate any input. ;-)

Comment: Also you could use [printf](https://linuxize.com/post/bash-printf-command/). That's an easy one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a "here document":

```
cat >> somefile.txt << "EOF"
BSPDIR := "${@os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(d.getVar('FILE', True)) + '/..')}"
EOF
```

Answer (score 0):

One simple thing you can do is to use single quotes. This way, the special characters will be considered as literal ones. Have a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6697753/difference-between-single-and-double-quotes-in-bash).

```sh
echo 'BSPDIR := "${@os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(d.getVar('FILE', True)) + '/..')}"'
```

Comment: This does not work when the text itself contains single quotes. In this case, the original single quotes disappear.